# Automatically verify signature on all Android Exchange emails

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, security, email, exchange, certificates

I work in an office where everyone uses a digital signature on their emails. I just bought a new LG G3 with 4.4.2 KitKat and whenever someone sends me an email that is signed, it shows up with a body that says "This email is signed". In order to see the contents, I have to open it and manually click the "Verify signature" button.

This is especially frustrating when I just want to preview the contents of the email right from my inbox but cannot.

Is there any way to have the phone automatically verify ALL signatures?

Comment: What email client are you using? The one that came with the phone, Gmail, or something else?

Comment: The default client